# 1.0==(.1*10) is False in python when looped

Tags: python, floating-point

I tried this code in Python  and found it surprising, can anyone explain this

```
x=0.0
for i in xrange(0,10):
    x=x+.1

print x #prints 1.0
print x==1.0#false
```

Comment: xrange(1,10) will only iterate 9 times. 0.1 * 9 != 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Because of [floating-point errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), the true value of `x` is `0.9999999999999999`, not `1.0`:

```
>>> x=0.0
>>> for i in xrange(0,10):
...     x=x+.1
...
>>> x
0.9999999999999999
>>>
```

Even though it is quite close, `0.9999999999999999` still does not equal `1.0`.  That is why Python is returning `False` for `x==1.0`.

---

The reason that `print x` is showing `1.0` is simply that `print` is rounding `x` to `1.0`:

```
>>> x = 0.9999999999999999
>>> print x
1.0
>>> x
0.9999999999999999
>>>
```

The true value of `x` still equals `0.9999999999999999` though.

---

As a final demonstration, let's remove the for-loop and add the numbers manually:

```
>>> x = 0.0
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.1
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.2
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.30000000000000004
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.4
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.5
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.6
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.7
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.7999999999999999
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.8999999999999999
>>> x += .1
>>> x
0.9999999999999999
>>>
```

As you can see, repeatedly adding `.1` to `0.0` generates a small but still noticeable floating-point error.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x
0.9999999999999999
>>> print x
1.0
```

It's floating point precision.